# How to calculate gas cost of an ETH transaction in USD?

Tags: blockchain, ether, etherscan, python

I am trying to calculate the dollar cost of ETH transactions using the following code:

```
response = requests.get('https://api.etherscan.io/api',params={'module':'account','action':'txlist','address':address,'startblock':'0','endblock':'99999999','sort':'desc','apikey':key})
```

As a result, I have the following data for the transactions:

```
['blockNumber', 'timeStamp', 'hash', 'nonce', 'blockHash',
       'transactionIndex', 'from', 'to', 'value', 'gas', 'gasPrice', 'isError',
       'txreceipt_status', 'input', 'contractAddress', 'cumulativeGasUsed',
       'gasUsed', 'confirmations', 'methodId', 'functionName']
```

Does anybody know how I might work those values to get the total gas cost in USD for that transaction? I know how to get ETH historical prices.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`gasUsed` * `gasPrice` should give you the cost in wei (10^18 wei = 1 ether). So you just need to get the ether price at `timeStamp` to get the price in whatever fiat you want.

Comment: What is the unit of `gasUsed` is it `gwei`?

Comment: @alper it is the same as `gas`, a measure without unit. It is just a number.